# UITableViewCell drawRect bottom border disappears on insertRow

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift2

I have a custom UITableViewCell where I use drawRect to paint a simple bottom border:

```
override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {   
   let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
   CGContextMoveToPoint(context, CGRectGetMinX(rect), CGRectGetMaxY(rect))
   CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, CGRectGetMaxX(rect), CGRectGetMaxY(rect))
   CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, UIColor(netHex: 0xEFEEF4).CGColor)
   CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 2)
   CGContextStrokePath(context)
}
```

This works perfectly. However when I insert a row with animation the borders of ALL cells disappear and appear again when insert animation finishes:

```
tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([NSIndexPath(forRow: cells.count - 1, inSection: 0)], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Fade)
```

Any idea how to avoid this?

Comment: I think you can achieve the same visual result with additional sublayer (CALayer with background colour and height) and avoid drawing at all. But it's of course not answer to your question:)

Comment: @sage444 if it is a working alternative please add it as an answer.

Comment: we can have a simple uiimageview of 2 pixels at the bottom of the cell from storyboard itself..and provide a color there...That will act as a border. ans also are you calling cell setNeedsDisplay.. in order to make the drawRect method call again?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well You can try this code in tablecell's **awakeFromNib** if you only want to use CALayers assuming that your TableView is covering the full width of the device.

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    let borderLayer = CALayer()
    let lineHeight:CGFloat = 2
    borderLayer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: self.frame.height - lineHeight , width: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width, height: lineHeight)
    borderLayer.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor().CGColor
    self.layer.addSublayer(borderLayer)
}
```

and you will get the output as:
[image]

Also make your tableview separator color to clear

```
self.tableView.separatorColor = UIColor.clearColor()
```

So that it doesn't gets overlapped with your layer.

What I can observe that now no borders of cells disappears ever whenever a new row is inserted.

**Alternatively**

We can just use a UIImageView in the cell storyboard and provide a color with the following constraints.
Adding UIImageView
[image]

Adding Constraints to UIImageView

[image]

And we are done!

There is one more **alternate** solution to achieve this using **Bezier Paths**

```
 override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    let line = CAShapeLayer()
    let linePath = UIBezierPath()
    linePath.moveToPoint(CGPointMake(0, self.frame.height))
    linePath.addLineToPoint(CGPointMake(UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width, self.frame.height))
    line.lineWidth = 3.0
    line.path = linePath.CGPath
    line.strokeColor = UIColor.redColor().CGColor
    self.layer.addSublayer(line)
 }
```

This also yields the same output.

**EDIT:**
If we are not using storyboards or nibs for the cell and creating the cell programatically, then we can do a workaround like this:

Create a property in your CustomTableViewCell class

```
var borderLayer:CALayer!
```

Now there is a method called layoutSubviews in CustomTableViewCell class

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    if(borderLayer != nil) {
        borderLayer.removeFromSuperlayer()
    }
    borderLayer = CALayer()
    let lineHeight:CGFloat = 2
    borderLayer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: self.frame.height - lineHeight , width: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width, height: lineHeight)
    borderLayer.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor().CGColor
    self.layer.addSublayer(borderLayer)
}
```

Try this out.

Comment: This also good answer, but why you not added UIImageView alternative instead of use my idea?

Comment: See I also do use CALayers and BezierPaths . For the UIImageView part it is much easier than adding layers and less complicated. Also UIImageView is of very little overhead. I ll update the alternative too in the answer.

Comment: Looking forward to see BezierPath

Comment: And your answer seems to be about separator, but question about border on the button

Comment: are you sure its about button? Its about tablecell with a bottom border

Comment: oh, sorry you are right, take +1, seems I meed another cup of coffee

Comment: @sage444 I am editing with another alternative using Bezier Paths. Here you go buddy!!

Comment: @sage444 I have edited with one more alternative. Have a look and please if there is any scope of improvement, do tell. Thanks

Comment: @RajanMaheshwari I dont use nib's, regrettably. My UITableView is inserted programmatically.

Comment: @artworkadシ No problem. I believe you have atleast a custom UITableViewClass for the cell?

Comment: Yes I habe a custom cell class

Comment: you have a method in customtableview cell as layoutSubviews.. code in it.. i will edit the answer in a second.
Edited. Pls check

Comment: @artworkadシ Please check the edited answer and let me know if was some help to you.

Comment: @RajanMaheshwari well it actually works. BUT on selection of a cell the background is not highlighted correctly. It does not take the full height.

Comment: @artworkadシ  Can you please show a screenshot + also what exactly do you want?

Answer (score 1):

It's not direct answer, just my suggestion how to achieve equal visual result without drawing.

See example code and result image

```
@IBOutlet weak var button: UIButton!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let layer = CALayer()
    let lineHeight:CGFloat = 2
    layer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: button.bounds.height - lineHeight , width: button.bounds.width, height: lineHeight)
    layer.backgroundColor = UIColor(colorLiteralRed: 0xEF/255.0, green: 0xEE/255.0, blue: 0xF4/255.0, alpha: 1).CGColor
    button.layer.addSublayer(layer)
}
```

Button and background view colors configured in IB.

[image]

Comment: I see the problem. I cannot put it into my UITableViewCell class because it has no viewDidLoad. When I put it into the init function of the class the height and width is not yet calculated by autolayout.

Comment: Oh, I used this method just for example, you can do it on awakeFromNib or in your custom setData method

Comment: why to complicate things.. just add a simple UIView or uiimage view of 2 pixels in storyboard cell itself with its height 2 pixels fixed and bottom constraint as 0 and left right as 0.. thats it..

Comment: @RajanMaheshwari you partially right, but UIView not quite the same as CALayer and in tableViewCell can add overhead

Comment: @sage444 So thats why I wrote we can use UIImageView rather than UIView.. that will be of very less overhead